# How to Migrate build.gradle from Groovy to Kotlin DSL in Android Studio Bumblebee?

Tags: android, build.gradle, migrate, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to migrate build.gradle file from Groovy to Kotlin, since I updated my Android Studio to Bumblebee, I'm not sure how to do it.

This is how build.gradle looks when I create a new project.

I'm not sure on how to migrate plugins{} part.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer in the documentation here https://developer.android.com/studio/build#kts.

Here's how it's written in Kotlin.

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.1.0-beta02" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.1.0-beta02" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.5.30" apply false
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me.

**Step-1**: Create the `plugins` tag and give it the `id` values. delete the `buildscript` tag.

[image]

**Step-2**: Open the `pluginManagement` tag in the `settings.gradle` file and make some tags and values.

[image]

**Step-3**: In the last step, update the values defined at the top in the `build.gradle` file as `id`.

[image]

**Optional**: Since it is in the `build.gradle` file, it must be deleted.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```